# What is the type of System.out in Java?

Tags: java, system.out, system.in

I am just a newbie in Java. I was wondering the way `System.out.println()` is used. Out is a static field inside `System` class. The type of `out` is `PrintStream`. But when I saw the constructor of `PrintStream` class, it takes a parameter of type `OutputStream` and as far as I know we cannot create the object of an abstract class. In that case we must pass some subclass's object to the constructor of `PrintStream`. What is that class? Same is the `System.in`. It is also `InputStream`'s reference but what is the type of object it points to as the `InputStream` is abstract?

Comment: You can use java's reflection to check all important object information at runtime.

Comment: Try `System.out.println(System.out.getClass());` or view it in your debugger. ;)

Comment: @PeterLawrey this will print `class java.io.PrintStream` nothing else :) The idea with debugger is more efficient ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`PrintStream` wraps `BufferedOutputStream`, which wraps `FileOutputStream`, which is writing into the console, which has its own `FileDescriptor`.

Comment: I'd like to add that the static field System.out does not have to be instantiatied by the user. It can be just used. My feeling is that the OP is having some trouble with understanding that.

Comment: @Fildor I have not that feeling. It seems to me, that it is just theoretical question.

Comment: Technically it is a `FileDescriptor`. The `File` class is not used.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Thanks, its my misprint. I'll fix it.

Answer (score 4):

A simple way to view the structure of a class is to examine it in a debugger.

As you can see @Andremonify's description is basically what you have.

FileDescriptor

- 0 is System.in
- 1 is System.out
- 2 is System.err
- 3+ is used for other files

[image]

Comment: `FileInputStream` for `stdin`, `FileOutputStream` for `stdout`. What about `stderr`

Comment: @overexchange stderr is much the same as stdout.

Comment: Correct. Can you also comment on first part of [query](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46953036/3317808)? about the idea of stream

Answer (score 1):

Yes `out` is of `PrintStream` type. And constructor of `PrintStream` takes `OutputStream` type. `OutputStream` is abstract class. *But any superclass refrence can refer subclass object without casting*, so PrintStream's constructor has `OutputStream` refrence, but this refrence must be referring one of `OutputStream`'s subclass like `FileOutputStream`

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple more things to say about the implementation of `System.out`.

1. The actual implementation class of `System.out` is *not specified*.  The javadocs don't say what it is.  *We observe* (in various way) that Oracle Java and OpenJDK Java implement the "stack" in a particular way (see other answers), but this *could* change in the future.
2. The `System::setOut(PrintStream)` method can be used to modify what `System.out` is bound to.  If that happens, any assumptions about implementation classes may be incorrect.
3. It turns out that you can do this:

   ```
     System.setOut(null);
   ```

   so `System.out` *could* be `null`.  However, with current implementations, `System.out` won't be `null` unless you set it to `null`.

All that is actually **guaranteed** by the specifications is that the value of `System.out` will have a type that is assignment compatible with `PrintStream`.

Comment: But we know the implementation class is either PrintStream or a subclass of PrintStream, right?

Comment: Yes.  That's more or less what "assignment compatible" means!  (But ... quibble ... `null` does not have an implementation class.  Which is why "assignment compatible" is technically more accurate than what you said.)