# InputStream/OutputStream for standard stream- Java

Tags: java

My understanding is, character streams and byte streams work internally over C `FILE *` stream.

[image]

standard streams in C world are `FILE * stdin`, `FILE *stdout` & `FILE *stderr`

---

[InputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html) and [OutputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html) are providing subclasses for resources like file, pipe...

### [image]

[InputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html) and [OutputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html) api documentation does not talk about [standard streams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams)- `stdin`/`stdout`/`stderr`.

---

Which subclass of `InputStream`/`OutputStream` dedicated for standard streams?

Comment: Feel free to remove this duplicate hammer, or add more duplicate links if you wish.  We can easily use `System.in` and `System.out` as input and output streams to access `stdin` and `stdout`.

Comment: Please see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html

Comment: Simply inspect what objects ``System.in`` and ``System.out`` are during runtime...

Comment: `InputStreamReader` is to read standard input stream

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I dont think this is a duplicate of the question you linked. Seems that OP is asking the *types* of stdin, stderr, stdout in java. Not *how* to read from them.

Comment: Your Wikipedia link tells you that it's System.in/out/err and includes links to [the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/System.html) which tells you the types of those variables.

Comment: voting to remove the duplicate tag

Comment: I removed the duplicate quesiton and replaced it with another. Does it look good now?

Comment: @vikingsteve I like the look of beige, even if I'm not the doing it :-)  ... maybe not an exact duplicate, but the issue is that the OP should not be using the classes he mentioned, he should use classes designed to work with `System.in` and `System.out`.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen if you feel its better to remove the duplicate and answer the question, that's fine too. Otherwise the OP is specifically looking for *types* and the short answer is: `PrintStream` and `InputStream`

Comment: @vikingsteve So, according to your referred duplicate,  `FileOutputStream` is working with `stdout`- `FileDescriptor`, `FileInputStream` works with `stdin`- `FileDescriptor`. What about `stderr`? Of course `PrintStream` is wrapping it via `BufferedInputStream` & `BufferedOutputStream`

Comment: Imagining a stream is always a mystery for java programmer except saying that it is implementation detail. Is java internally relying on C `FILE *` stream?

Comment: @vikingsteve `InputStream` is an abstract class. How would you talk to `stdin` & `stderr`? You are using lot of energy in finding duplicates.

Comment: Ok I will removed the duplicate and you can answer it if you have time. There was a different dubplicate posted by Tim, I changed it to a better one.

Comment: Your understanding is incorrect. `FILE *` has nothing to do with it. Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: @EJP Stream is a sequential buffer created on opening a resource. Contents of a resource are copied to that buffer. This buffer is the source that is read/write from/to. `FILE *` is a stream in C world. Does java rely on `FILE *`? What is that unclear for you that so many users here are talking about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look in the source for `System` class, you can see the following types:

```
public final static PrintStream out = null;
public final static PrintStream err = null;
public final static InputStream in = null;
```

i.e. stdin and stderr are of type `PrintStream` and stdin is `InputStream`.

Naturally, we should access them via `System.out.println()` and similar operations.

In relation to the `Inputstream` / `OutputStream` that you showed in your question, `PrintStream` extends `FilterOutputStream` which extends `OutputStream`. The main purpose of `PrintStream` is to add useful functions of the style `print()`, `println()` and so on.

Comment: `FileInputStream(FileDescriptor fdObj)` where `fdObj` can be 0 for `stdin`. `FileOutputStream(FileDescriptor fdObj)` where `fdObj` can be 1 for `stdout` and 2 for `stderr`.

Comment: System.out and System.err are PrintStream rather than InputStream for convenience and assumes you want to write text. Somewhat inconsistently, `in` is not a BufferedReader` or a `Scanner` which would have been useful. Instead we have `Console` class.